# Output matrix correctly in Spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I would like to know how I go about getting the correct output, I want the output to have the same format as the input. I'm just not quite sure how to map a `rowNatrix` to have this output.

Input File

```
0,0,0.0
0,1,1.0
0,2,2.0
0,3,3.0
0,4,4.0
1,0,5.0
1,1,6.0
1,2,7.0
1,3,8.0
1,4,9.0
```

Code

```
String inputPathA = "data/At.txt";
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

JavaRDD<String> fileA = sc.textFile(inputPathA);

JavaRDD<MatrixEntry> matrixA = fileA.map(new Function<String, MatrixEntry>() {
    public MatrixEntry call(String x){
        String[] indeceValue = x.split(",");
        long i = Long.parseLong(indeceValue[0]);
        long j = Long.parseLong(indeceValue[1]);
        double value = Double.parseDouble(indeceValue[2]);
        return new MatrixEntry(i, j, value );
    }
});

CoordinateMatrix cooMatrixA = new CoordinateMatrix(matrixA.rdd());
BlockMatrix matA = cooMatrixA.toBlockMatrix();
BlockMatrix ata = matA.transpose().multiply(matA);
IndexedRowMatrix id = ata.toIndexedRowMatrix();
RowMatrix rm = id.toRowMatrix();
RDD<Vector> result = rm.rows();
result.saveAsTextFile("data/output1")
```

the output I get

```
(5,[0,1,2,3,4],[45.0,58.0,71.0,84.0,97.0])
(5,[0,1,2,3,4],[25.0,30.0,35.0,40.0,45.0])
(5,[0,1,2,3,4],[30.0,37.0,44.0,51.0,58.0])
(5,[0,1,2,3,4],[40.0,51.0,62.0,73.0,84.0])
(5,[0,1,2,3,4],[35.0,44.0,53.0,62.0,71.0])
```

How do I map that correctly in Spark (Java) to be the same as my input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rowMatrix` has no meaningful row indices so it cannot be converted back to the same shape as an input. Instead you simply convert `BlockMatrix` back to `CoordinateMatrix` and prepare `JavaRDD<String>` which can be saved:

```
JavaRDD<MatrixEntry> entries = ata.toCoordinateMatrix().entries().toJavaRDD();
JavaRDD<String> output = entries.map(new Function<MatrixEntry, String>() {
    public String call(MatrixEntry e) {
        return String.format("%d,%d,%s", e.i(), e.j(), e.value());
    }
});
output.saveAsTextFile("data/output1");
```